# LOGSTASH -check status if successful

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logstash with input-elasticsearch and output-elasticsearch.I want to know whether the configuration ran successfully.Does logstash provide some sort of status code or some other thing for this purpose?

I am using config like this-

```
input{
elasticsearch{
hosts=>"abc.de.fg.hi:jklm"
query=>'{--some query---}'
}
}
output{

elasticsearch{
hosts=>"xxx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy"

}
```

Comment: A lack of errors (in the logs, or perhaps the LS5 API), and the presence of data in the new cluster are probably the best bets.

Comment: Any other way to get acknowledgement from logstash?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could test your configuration in your cmd by typing in:

```
./logstash -f yourfile.conf -t
```

You could also see the other operands you could use by typing:

```
./logstash --help
```

OR you could have a look at all the [flags](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/command-line-flags.html) you can use. Hope it helps!

Comment: This will tell you if the config is *valid*, not if it *ran*.

Comment: Exactly I want to know if it ran.